# How can I search for files in all sub-directories using the shell and then copy those files?

Tags: command-line

How can I find just the *.mp3 files with a recursive command like `ls -R *.mp3` in a directory that contains several sub-directories and at the end copy these files in a directory that I choose.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 14):

The command is:

```
find /path/to/directory -name "*.mp3" -exec cp {} /some/other/dir/ \;
```

Alternative:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -name '*.mp3' | xargs cp -t /target/
```

Example:

```
alex@MaD-pc:~/test$ ls
1  2  3
alex@MaD-pc:~/test$ ls 1 2 3
1:
1.txt  2.mp3  3.txt

2:
4.txt  5.mp3  6.txt

3:
alex@MaD-pc:~/test$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec cp {} 3/ \;
alex@MaD-pc:~/test$ ls 3
2.mp3  5.mp3
```

For more information:

```
man find
```

Comment: Judges would also accept: `find /path/to/dir/ -name '*.c' | xargs cp -t /target/`

Comment: I am one of the judges and I deny this solution 8-) Thanks for the comment, I will add it :)

Comment: `xargs` is normally a *lot* quicker. I've just run a quick test here finding a load of c files and and run `ls -l` on them. It's 0m2.420s for `xargs` and 0m25.494s for `-exec`... Clearly in this case the `cp` operation is going to take most of the time so it probably doesn't matter but it's worth keeping note of.

Comment: I would recommend  adding the `-n`` switch to the `cp` command to avoid overwrite in the case of duplicate names (or writing a script that checks for duplicates prior to copy and renaming the target as necessary)

Answer (score 2):

There is also another way to do it which I think will suit your purpose perfectly. You can combine `find` with a `while` loop and not even need to use either of `exec` or `xargs` at all. If, for example you wanted to copy your `mp3s` from your download folder to your music folder, you would use the following script, which I have used many times.

You can modify it how you want by changing the directories that `find` searches and places the resulting files in; if no directory is stated, `find` will search the entire home folder. You can also change `cp` to `mv` or other commands. It is pretty fast, as I have just tested it with 3945 `.jpg` files! Copy it into a text editor, save it and then make it executable by running `chmod +x myscript`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# a script to recursively find and copy files to a desired location
find ~/Downloads -type f -iname '*.mp3' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; 
do cp -- "$f" ~/Music ;
done
```

[At this noted Bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) it is shown how useful it is to combine the `while` loop and `read` commands to process the output of the `find` command; and the way I have done it makes sure that the script will not break if it comes across file names with spaces or other unexpected or special characters.

For more general information on the `find` command, enter in the terminal `man find` or see the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html). For a great introduction to the use of find, see [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind/) as well.

Comment: isn't `find ~/Downloads -type f -iname '*.mp3' | while read mp3file; do cp "$mp3file" ~/Music; done` simpler?

Comment: My method represents best practice and prevents the script from breaking, as noted at the link I quoted.

Comment: ah, I see, that takes care of handling special characters, thanks for the link :)

Comment: I would recommend  adding the `-n`` switch to the `cp` command to avoid overwrite in the case of duplicate names (or writing a script that checks for duplicates prior to copy and renaming the target as necessary)